# Control of a LED with Android and Arduino

Tags: android

I'm practicing with my new play, an arduino micro and a bluetooth module Hc-05.

I'm trying to turn on and turn off a Led connected in the 13th digital pin of my arduino. The LED is controlled by my android, I've made an application with App Inventor. I don't know why, but my little project doesn't work. Can you help me?

Here is my code.

Thank you very much!

```
void setup()
{


// Pin 13 Digital de Arduino
 pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
 // Velocidad serial del Modulo BT
 Serial.begin(9600);
}
char led; // Led es nuestro led conectado a Arduino
void loop()
{


 if (Serial.available())
 // Siclo if para definir que se acción se ejecutara si Arduino recibe el dato "a" (si lo recibe el led se enciende)
 {
 led=(Serial.read());
 if (led=='a')
 {
 digitalWrite(13, HIGH);

 }
 if (led=='b')
 // Siclo if para definir que se acción se ejecutara si Arduino recibe el dato "b" (si lo recibe el led se apaga)
 {
 digitalWrite(13, LOW);
 }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a similar project - smar LED for motorcycle. There is an app for Atmega328P almost ready, see https://github.com/AlexShutov/LED_LIGHTS_Controller project on Android site I managed to connect to Bluetooth device and switch color of RGB Led. check project https://github.com/AlexShutov/LEDLights . For communication via Bluetooth it uses slightely modified version of Google sample: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat